# private method `main_image' called for nil:NilClass? how to fix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

portfolios_controller.rb

```
class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @portfolio_items = Portfolio.all 
  end

  def new
    @portfolio_item =Portfolio.new
  end

  def create
    @portfolio_item =Portfolio.new(params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :subtitle, :body))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Your Portfolio Item is now live.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @blog }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.update(params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :subtitle, :body))
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'The record successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end 
end

def show
   @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
end
```

---

show.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag @portfolio_item.main_image %>

<h1><%= @portfolio_item.title %></h1>

<em><%= @portfolio_item.subtitle %></em>

<p><%= @portfolio_item.body %></p>
```

Comment: Please post your `Portfolio` model.

Comment: Wellcome to SO, try to provide all the information about your question (in this case the complete error message would be helpful).

Comment: I fixed your indentation, which revealed the fact that your `show` action is outside of the class. You'll want to fix that and then see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Add `show` action

```
def show
  @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
end
```

In your `portfolios_controller`

Answer (score 0):

> private method `main_image' called for nil:NilClass?

You are **ending the class** `PortfoliosController` before `show` method, so it lost the scope. Put it **inside** the `PortfoliosController`

```
def update
  @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @portfolio_item.update(params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :subtitle, :body))
      format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'The record successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end 

def show
   @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
end
end #class end
```